# Klarna payment not showing in Magento 2.4 frontend checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, klarna, klarnacheckout

I am adding Klarna API username and Klarna API password and enable it.
Then on going to checkout page it doesn't show on frontend.

I am using Magento 2.4.

Is there any issue with klarna with magento 2.4.

Comment: Please enable Logging from module to get more details

Comment: Thanks for your response it was a currency issue i have selected USD so need to change to Pound Sterling for UK and it works.

Comment: glad to know :) it worked for you.